# Is every countably infinite subset of a metric space closed?

Tags: metric-spaces

It seems that the answer is no, but I'm struggling to think of a proper example.

Would I be best trying to think of a closed set whose complement is open?

Comment: The complement of a closed set is always open... (that is the definition of a closed set, by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual metric)

Comment: Didn't realise the answer could be as simple as that. Thanks very much

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$
S:=\left\{\frac{1}{n}: n\ge 1\right\}
$ 
is neither closed nor open (in the usual topology of $\mathbf{R}$).